# Meaning of the phrase "$X'$ can be identified with a subspace of $X$"?

Tags: linear-algebra, exact-sequence

The following is taken from

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{Exercise}$  Show that if a sequence

$$0\xrightarrow{}X'\xrightarrow{}X\xrightarrow{}X''\xrightarrow{}0$$

is exact, then $X'$ can be identified with a subspace of $X$ and $X''$ with $X/X'.$

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

For the above exercise, what does it mean by "$X'$ can be identified with a subspace of $X$?"

Thank you in advance

Comment: It means there is an injection $\iota$ of $X’$ into $X$. Then, $\iota[X’]$ is isomorphic to $X’$, and is a subspace of $X$. So, we have an isomorphic copy of $X’$ sitting inside $X$; this is the ‘identification’ referred to.

Comment: @peek-a-boo is similar reasoning apply to $X''$ with $X/X'$?

Comment: yes ‘can be identified’ means ‘is isomorphic to’, and for this second claim you’ll want to use the first isomorphism theorem.